# Book Proposal Template

Tags: templates

Are there any templates to help produce a nonfiction book **proposal**? My book idea is moderately technical, on the topic of e-commerce, but my audience will be executives.

Based on some research, a nonfiction book proposal generally follows this format:

```
# Cover Page
    Title
    Name
    Contact Info

# Header/Footer (every page)
    Title
    Last Name

# Introduction
    1-3 page hard pitch

# Contents
    Table of contents

# Biography
    About the author
    Previous publications

# Audience/Market
    Market segment
    Sales channels

# Competition
    Competitive and comparative titles

# Publicity and Promotion

# Chapter Summaries
    1-2 paragraphs per chapter

# Sample Chapter
```

References

[1] http://wolflit.com/how-to-write-a-nonfiction-book-proposal/
[2] http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/07/10/nonfiction-book-proposal_n_3569043.html

I am relatively new to LaTeX, and discovered the *memoir* class yesterday. I don't know if that can be tweaked to meet my needs though.

Comment: And the relation to TeX? For a proposal you could start with the `book` class. Then, a basic template would be `\documentclass{book} \begin{document} ... \end{document}`

Comment: And this deserves a down vote?

Comment: not for me. I think that your question can be improved.

Comment: For instance you could give some criteria that your propsal form should satisfy.

Comment: book class ....

Comment: You can also use the "report" class to get a fine result as well.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I did recently edit it to make it more "acceptable" to the downvoters.